# ¿Como convertir un arreglo de int a string c++

Tags: c++, array, c, string, punteros

necesito hacer una función que tome los elementos de un puntero de int, y los convierta a una variable de tipo string para retornarla en la función, el problema es que si bien no me da errores la función, no me retorna nada

```
string Vector1::toString(){
    string conversor, conversorAux;
    for(int i=0;i<size();i++){
        conversor[i]=*(elementos+i);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<size();i++){
        conversorAux[i]=conversor[i];
    }
    return conversorAux;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Para convertir un array de `int` a `std::string` no necesitas más que un bucle:

```
std::string resultado;
for( int value : elementos)
{
    resultado += std::to_string(elementos);
}
```

En tu caso, imagino que tienes varios problemas:

**No estás haciendo conversiones**

```
int elementos[];
std::string conversor;

for(int i=0;i<size();i++){
    conversor[i]=*(elementos+i);
}
```

En este caso, en cada posición de `conversor` no estás guardando la representación en caracteres del dígito almacenado en `elementos[i]` sino el dígito en si mismo. Dicho de otra forma, no es lo mismo el caracter `'0'` que el dígito `0`. Al segundo le corresponde el valor `0`, mientras que al primero le corresponde `0x30` (puedes acudir a cualquier tabla ASCII para comprobarlo).

Resumiendo, lo que estás guardando en `conversor` son caracteres no imprimibles.

**acceso peligroso a string**

```
std::string conversor;

for(int i=0;i<size();i++){
    conversor[i]=/* ... */;
}
```

Este código da a entender que no conoces cómo funciona la clase `std::string`. Esta clase podríamos representarla con el siguiente código:

```
class string
{
public:
    // Interfaz pública
private:
    size_t size;
    char* ptr;
};
```

Es decir, por detrás no es más que un puntero de tipo `char` y una variable para conocer la cantidad máxima de caracteres que entran en la memoria direccionada por el puntero.

El operador `[]` se implementaría más o menos así:

```
class string
{
public:
    char& operator[](size_t index)
    {
        return ptr[index];
    }
};
```

Es decir, en este operador no se obra ninguna magia que permita incrementar la capacidad de `ptr`. Si en algún momento intentas escribir fuera de los límites del array, esta función no te va a parar los pies.

No puedes rellenar un array con el operador [] sin garantizar antes que el string tiene la capacidad suficiente. Por ejemplo:

```
std::string resultado;
resultado.reserve(size()+1);

for(int i=0;i<size();i++){
    conversor[i]=*(elementos+i);
}
conversor[size()] = '\0';
```

En este ejemplo estaríamos garantizando una capacidad mínima en el string que nos permite utilizar el operador `[]` con seguridad.